# Как отследить движение телефона вверх вниз?

Tags: c#, unity3d

мне нужно отследить движение мобильного устройства
до сих пор не понимаю как.

читал что с этим связан акселерометр, я попробовал написать небольшой код задающий движение объекту исходя из данных акселерометра по каждой из осей, и понял то что , по всей видимости он отслеживает только лишь вращение но не положение устройства в пространстве.

что мне конкретно нужно :

при движении устройства вверх/вниз , двигать игровой объект также вверх или вниз

не понимаю как это реализовать правильно, видел что можно считать встряхивание , возможно мне стоит копать туда, поэтому я пока этим и занимаюсь.

буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: За это отвечает компас, а не акселерометр. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Compass.html ах да,  если телефон его не поддерживает, то это не будет работать .

Comment: @こきん спасибо!, сейчас попробую

Comment: @こきん не понимаю почему он не работает, сделал все как в документации, но при передвижении устройства куб просто стоит на месте :/ (компас поддерживает, он тут встроен)